# Errors in bash script. Syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash, shell

Do you know what is wrong with my script as I always get the error mesage:

```
position frac1 frac2
: command not found: 
'/s1_met.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `do
'/s1_met.sh: line 3: `for lineF1 in $(cat $1); do
```

Code here:

```
export IFS=$'\n'
echo "position frac1 frac2";  
for lineF1 in $(cat $1); do
    if [ $(echo $lineF1 | cut -b 1-2) = "##" ]; then
       echo "skip line" >&2;
    else
       startF1=$(echo $lineF1 | cut -f 4);
       stopF1=$(echo $lineF1 | cut -f 5);
       fracF1=$(echo $lineF1 | cut -f 9 | cut -d ";" -f 4 | cut -d "=" -f 2);

       lineF2=$(grep "$startF1" $2);
       if [ -z "$lineF2" ]; then
          echo "position $startF1 cannot be found" >&2;
       else
          fracF2=$(echo $lineF2 | cut -f 9 | cut -d ";" -f 4 | cut -d "=" -f 2);
          echo "$startF1 $fracF1 $fracF2";
       fi;
    fi
done;
```

Comment: [Line-endings issue](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)?

Comment: Just a comment, you do not need to be placing a semi-colon `;` at the end of each line, your not coding in `C`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with it, you must not be running it with BASH.

Edited to say you need to check your line endings, your comment below with the ^M means that you have extra characters on the line.  See here.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Try putting the "shebang" line in the script [shebang docs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)

To do this, run `which bash` which will tell you something like `/bin/bash`.  Your script should then be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "I'm running with bash!"
```

Try that, your syntax is OK.

Comment: Yes, what does `which bash` say?

Comment: Right, it's the line endings.  You have Windows style line endings in the unix file, so when you have `#!/bin/bash^M` it is not valid, you need `#!/bin/bash` without the line ending.  See the link I posted, it is "invisible" in your editor but you need to fix the file.  Not sure why I got voted -1, because what I said is correct.

Comment: Mikeb, you was right. I fixed my file and it finaly works ! Thanks a lot for your help. :)